# "What" instead of "that/which"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, clauses

I remember coming across usage of "**what**" in place of "**that/which**". Is it very old usage or some dialect, or maybe it's plain wrong? One phrase I remember a hundred percent is:

- The secrets what lie within.

Comment: I have never seen or heard this form before, Alex. When I just Googled it, I got the title of a book, *The Secrets **that** Lie Within*, by Vicky Arledge and Kerry Hearns-Smith. The title of the book is how I've always heard it said; I've never heard it said your way, but here's an answer I wrote a few days ago regarding "what" that may helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152338/what-appears-to-be-or-what-appear-to-be/152357#152357.

Comment: I think of it as characteristic of Cockney or other working-class English dialects.  If you do a google search for the exact phrase "the man what done it," you'll find some discussion of this.

Comment: @CanadianYankee So it may be Cockney English?

Comment: @Nick I know that usage of **what** thanks. It's not what I was looking for.

Comment: @SovereignSun Yes, and it would be heard by certain people as "uneducated" or incorrect.

Comment: Yes, it's a feature of some dialects.  For example, there's a play called [*The Play What I Wrote*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Play_What_I_Wrote) by two British comedians (although I think they were making fun of dialect speakers).

Comment: @stangdon So it is a dialect and it is bad English altogether?

Comment: Sometimes, to emphasize that it's dialect, you'll even see it spelled as "wot," in attempt to mimic the pronunciation.  [Here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=LXlR0QnnrMMC&pg=PA266&lpg=PA266&dq=%22the+man+wot+done+it%22&source=bl&ots=0Xir4TRtpf&sig=APbNmCqUJOUIFzW4skhzkVpYTLg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJx9H0ssHYAhWJ5oMKHUtrAy8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20man%20wot%20done%20it%22&f=false) is an example from a novel where a (presumably not-well-educated) police sergeant is quoted as saying, " 'Ave you got the man wot done it, Mr. Pitt?"

Comment: It's definitely characteristic of certain BrE dialects including Cockney. Canadian Yankee is right. It is dialectal. Not bad English, just English as spoken by some people. All language is fine; even fucked up, screwed up language. Linguists describe language, they don't take a moral position.

Comment: @Nick LOL I found a couple of examples. [Here's](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ej49AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA233&dq=%22wot+I%27ve+seed+her+done%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUhvy6uMLYAhVMsFMKHYKAB70Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22wot%20I've%20seed%20her%20done%22&f=false) one, and [here's](https://books.google.com/books?id=jENAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA618&dq=%22wot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwioweX7t8LYAhUCv1MKHbsECJY4ChDoAQgtMAE#v=onepage&q=%22wot%22&f=false) another, with a whole mess of examples.

Comment: AvE on you tube uses what in that way: [There's a mite, what lives in there"]( https://youtu.be/MYBamOW7YFc?t=2m02s ).

Comment: I recall **["it's people like you what cause unrest"](https://genius.com/Monty-python-fish-licence-lyrics)* from an old Monty Python recording.

Comment: See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162619/usage-of-what-for-that-or-than-in-bre) on ELU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not purely British, there are American regional uses of it. It's not merely a quirk but representative of a deeper or older usage. In Spanish for example "que" can mean either "what" or "that" depending on context. Same in Jamaican Patois from what I've heard.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELL. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion; can you support it with references?